# Why Flatlist isn't rendering properly when android build apk orientation changes?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

I'm using expo to build a pantry service app and I'm fetching a list of items from a node pantry server then render them on the app using Flatlist.

- Everything works as expected except for one thing and that is the flatlist rendering when Orientation changes.
- When testing with the expo app it works flawlessly even when the orientation changes.
- Problem: When building android apk and testing it on device flatlist no longer renders as expected and for instance:

-> When starting the app in portrait mode you can scroll all the way to the bottom but when you rotate the device I'm unable to scroll all the way to the bottom or it seems I can but the rest of the items seem to be clipped beyond the device display borders.

[image: Sample 1]

-> Conversely when I start the app in landscape mode I'm able to scroll to the bottom with no issue but when I change the orientation to portrait the flatlist renders only half way through the screen, I'm still able to scroll to the end of it.

[image: Sample 2]

I've tried passing to extraData as well add flexgrow to contentContainerStyle,I've also tried using ScrollView instead of View but there are no noticeable improvements.

```
const [refreshing,setRefreshing] = useState(false)

ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener(
    evt => {
      setCurrOrientation(evt.orientationInfo.orientation)
      setRefreshing(!refreshing)
    }
  )

ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync().then(result => setCurrOrientation(result.orientation))

keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

  renderItem = ({ item,index }) => (
    <ListItem
      key={index}
      leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: BASE_URL + ':' + PORT + '/uploads/' + item.rowid + '/image.png' } }}
      title={<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'fake-receipt' }}>{item.item_name}</Text>}
      subtitle={<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'fake-receipt', color: 'grey', fontSize: 10 }}>{item.item_type}</Text>}
      containerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: '#F0F0F0', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomStartRadius: 10, borderTopStartRadius: 10 }}
      onPress={() => {
        setSelectedItemIndex(index);
        setSelectedItemRowID(item.rowid);
        setSelectedItemSugarCondition(item.sugar === 'yes' ? 'yes' : 'no');
        setOverlayVisible(true);
      }}
      rightIcon={<IconFA name={'plus'}
        size={20}
        color='#26a69a'
      />}

    />
  )

<View>
          <FlatList
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            extraData={refreshing}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            data={itemsList}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
          />
</View>
```

Its puzzling me how it works fine in the expo app but not the expo android build, any ideas how I can fix this or if there is a better alternative?

I'm using expo 3.0.10 and device is running Android 9 Pie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I used Dimensions with another view and placed flatlist inside it, this rendered the flatlist properly after orientation.

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1', flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{height:Dimensions.get('window').height - 80}}>
          <FlatList
            extraData={refreshing}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            data={itemsList}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
          />
        </View>
</View>
```